# readFileSync cant find file

Tags: node.js

I've read multiple threads here on Stackoverflow, but can get this to work.

My file (that exists, have double checked) that i try to read is located in

```
/src/files/2022.json
```

I have tried both relative path and direct path.

Output for debuging returns the following
process.cwd() = "/Users/MYNAME/Dropbox/Mac/Documents/projects/checker-be"
__dirname = "/Users/MYNAME/Dropbox/Mac/Documents/projects/checker-be/src/helpers"

I have tried the following code, which outputs the error message below the code:

```
fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../files/2022.json'), {encoding:'utf8', flag:'r'});
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/MYNAME/Dropbox/Mac/Documents/projects/checker-be/src/files/2022.json'

fs.readFileSync('./src/files/2022.json', {encoding:'utf8', flag:'r'});
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './src/files/2022.json'
```

What am I doing wrong? If Im missing posting something, please let me now.

Comment: usually it's `C://Users/...` also since it's a json file, try `require('./src/files/2022.json')` ;-;

Comment: @TheBombSquad OP is almost certainly on a mac...

Comment: perhaps perhaps.. however the `require` part should return `JSON.parse(whatever_was_in_2022)`

Comment: Hey John, open up your terminal.app and run (without quotes and substituting your actual home dir) "cat /Users/MYNAME/Dropbox/Mac/Documents/projects/checker-be/src/files/2022.json". Does it error?